# Mongodb doesn't start as a service

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04

When I try to run Mongodb as a service `sudo service mongodb start`
I get

[mongodb.log on pastebin.com](http://pastebin.com/yF09dniM)

and service doesn't start. But simple run `mongod` works well. Sorry, but still can't google a solution.

Comment: if you connect to the instance after running `mongod` you'll probably find it has no dbs & collections. Chances are you're not using the default data path. If you look in your log (the stack trace) it appears one of your data files is corrupt. `isOk` verifies if your database is "is ok" and there seems to be an issue there preventing it from completing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is removing all data from mongo data (Ty Blizz)

For my case clear `/var/lib/mongodb`